# What happened to the spider that bit Peter Parker?

Tags: movie, comics, spider-man, marvel

Do we know what happened to the radioactive spider after it bit Peter Parker?

Did it bite anyone else or did it just live out the rest of its spider-life in peace?

Comment: Follow up question:  If the spider had survived, and bit a fly (but didn't kill it), would the fly become Spider-Fly?

Comment: What if it bit another spider... Spider-spider?

Comment: What if Spider-Man bit a person?  Spider-Man-Man?

Comment: @WadCheber No, it would become Jeff Goldblum.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I wish I could become Jeff Goldblum.

Comment: @WadCheber Don't worry. Life, uh, uh, finds a way.

Comment: The Spider bites the dust. The dust becomes the... **Amazing Spider-Dust**! See *Amazing Fantasy 15*. In the the 2014 retcon, it bites Cindy Moon (becoming Silk) before it bites the dust (which becomes Spider-Dust-Silk or Dust-Silk or Spider-Silk or whatever).

Comment: **Much more interesting** is what happens to the **spider silk strand** seen in the comic *Amazing Fantasy 15*. After a few days, during regular lab cleaning, it is broken into dust particles and removed from the lab. Eventually the spider silk dust particles are blown all over the world...becoming an awesome World Wide Web...with the power of LOL-Cats --- and Trolling. As proven by this very comment.

Comment: It became Man-Spider.

Comment: What if an an old lady swallowed that fly?   I guess she'll die.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The Comics

In *Amazing Fantasy 15*, it dies from massive radiation exposure.

[image: Falsely accused spider-murderer]

Transcript:

> But, as the experiment begins, no one notices a tiny spider, descending from the ceiling on an almost invisible strand of web...
>
> A spider whom fate has given a starring, if brief, role to play in the drama we call life!
>
> Accidentally absorbing a fantastic amount of radiation the dying insect, in sudden shock, bites the nearest living thing, at the split second before life ebbs from its radioactive body!

As [Kimberly W](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/97178/31051) points out in another answer here, this was retconned in 2014 to provide the origin story of the newly-introduced hero Silk.

### *Spider-man* (2002)

In the movie itself, we see the spider crawl under some equipment in the Oscorp lab immediately after it bites Peter:

Interestingly, this is contradicted by the film's novelization<sup>1</sup>, where the spider dies immediately:

> [Peter] looked down, his eyes narrowing, as he watched what appeared to be a spider flip over onto its back, its legs curling up like something out of a commercial for Raid.

### *The Amazing Spider-man*

The spider's fate isn't shown on-screen, but it seems most likely that Peter killed it immediately after it bit him:

[image: Peter Parker, the Amazing Spider-murderer?]

His hand is right over where the spider bit him and, though we don't actually see it in the movie, at least my reaction to a sharp biting sensation on my skin is to smack the affected area with extreme prejudice.

---

<sup>1</sup> Due thanks to Richard for the quote

Comment: I just saw the movie yesterday, and I *think* the spider got away with his life.  I'll see if I can find any evidence to support this belief.

Comment: Inconclusive.  He seems to touch the bite mark rather than swat the spider, but it is impossible to say with certainty.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLSxT-uzA7Q

Comment: Interestingly, the novelisation for Spider Man disagrees with the film *"He looked down, his eyes narrowing, as he watched what appeared to be a spider flip over onto its back, its legs curling uplike something out of a commercial for Raid."*

Comment: @Richard That's the novelization for Raimi's *Spider-man*, I assume? Mind if I borrow the quote, or did you want to make your own answer?

Comment: @JasonBaker - Raimi #1, yes. Feel free to use the quote

Comment: @Richard Cheers

Comment: @JasonBaker - Did you notice that someone at Marvel Comics seems to believe that spiders are insects?  At least the dumb SOB is still paying the price for his stupidity, some 50 years later.

Comment: @WadCheber I did notice, although I wouldn't exactly say he's paying for his stupidity; more like he's [getting paid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stan_Lee#Later_career)

Comment: STAN THE MAN WROTE THAT?  My brain just exploded.

Comment: @WadCheber Well, he got credit for it. Stan Lee has been known to hog credit, from time to time

Comment: I'm pretty sure in the Amazing Spider-Man the dead spider hangs from the thread that comes out of Peter and he has to rip it off.

Comment: Am I the only one OCD enough to be bothered by the fact that the comic book writers called the spider an insect?  I probably am.

Comment: Correction to The Amazing Spiderman: the spider is shown dead, it's just shown in a later scene once Peter comes home. Peter goes to the bathroom and, for some reason I don't understand, finds a string of web leading from the bitemark, at the other end of which is the dead spider: https://imgur.com/fgZsab5.

Answer (score 9):

After biting Peter Parker it bit Cindy Moon (aka Silk) and then died. Cindy exhibits similar powers to Peter such as wall crawling and spider sense. Interestingly, she can make organic webbing from her finger tips. The two also share a pheromone connection that makes each attracted to the other. Check out [Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 3 #4](http://marvel.wikia.com/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_3_4).

The following is an photo taken from this issue. Parker just received secret memories from the Watcher's Eye and can't believe what he's seeing.

> Parker: The spider! After it bit me -- it bit someone else?! A girl? I
>   -- never knew! Who is she?
>
> Mrs. Moon: Cindy!
>
> Cindy: Mom! Dad! I can't control it!

[image: Peter Park sees Cindy Moon for the first time.]

Answer (score 3):

so Silk/Cindy Moon has already been mentioned but there was another person who apparently encountered the spider that bit Peter; Carl King. he was apparently one of Peters bullies and he ate (I know, ew) the spider that bit Peter and it turned him into a sentient swarm of spiders called "The Thousand". think Million Ants from Rick and Morty but significantly more horrifying.[image: picture of The Thousand]

[image: picture of Million Ants]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is good info, but you could really improve your answer by telling us which issue this appeared in.

Answer (score 1):

**In the Marvel Cinematic Universe:**

According to Peter Parker, the spider is dead:

> "The spider's dead, Ned."
>
> -Peter Parker, *Spider-Man: Homecoming* (2017, Sony Pictures)

This comment is sparked from Ned asking if the spider could bite him.